# How Responsive Web Development is Different than Progressive Web Development?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

what is the difference between progressive and Responsive web app development?

check https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps?hl=en

Comment: Do you mean progressive enhancement?

Comment: nope check https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Progressive Web Apps are many things, including responsive:

- Progressive - Work for every user, regardless of browser choice because they’re built with progressive enhancement as a core tenet.
- Responsive - Fit any form factor: desktop, mobile, tablet, or whatever is next.
- Connectivity independent - Enhanced with service workers to work offline or on low quality networks.
- App-like - Feel like an app to the user with app-style interactions and navigation because it's built on the app shell model.
- Fresh - Always up-to-date thanks to the service worker update process.
- Safe - Served via HTTPS to prevent snooping and ensure content hasn’t been tampered with.
- Discoverable - Are identifiable as “applications” thanks to W3C manifests and service worker registration scope allowing search engines to find them.
- Re-engageable - Make re-engagement easy through features like push notifications.
- Installable - Allow users to “keep” apps they find most useful on their home screen without the hassle of an app store.
- Linkable - Easily share via URL and not require complex installation.

https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps?hl=en#learnmore